# Image not uploading on server while it is working well in localhost

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.9

I am trying to save an image to a folder when a user uploads the image and submits the signup form.

In models.py

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True)
```

I have used a function `upload_location` to upload the images, here it is

```
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    UserModel = instance.__class__
    new_id = UserModel.objects.order_by("id").last().id + 1
    return "user/%s/%s" %(new_id,filename)
```

It is working perfectly in localhost, but it is not even hitting function `upload_location` when i push the code to server. What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT :** 
Came to know the actual problem. File size of more than 15kb is not uploading on server. Is this the django issue or server issue?

Comment: What do the error logs say?

Comment: If its not even calling `upload_location()` then why are you posting the function? Its unlikely to be the problem if it doesn't even get called. Check in your Browser "view request" page, if the image gets actually transferred. And check in your Django view, if the image data actually arrives. That would be the first step.

Comment: Came to know the actual problem. File size of more than 15kb is not uploading on server. Is this the django issue or server issue?